# send message to gitlab-ci merge request from pipeline

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci

i have a pipeline in gitlab-ci started  from a merge request .

i would like after my step "plan " sent a result in my merge request for validation but my code don't run correctly because i meet an error during a POST  event.

```
 - terragrunt plan -out=$PLAN
  - echo \`\`\`diff > plan.txt
  - terragrunt show ${PLAN} | tee -a plan.txt
  - echo \`\`\` >> plan.txt
  - sed -i -e 's/  +/+/g' plan.txt
  - sed -i -e 's/  ~/~/g' plan.txt
  - sed -i -e 's/  -/-/g' plan.txt
  - MESSAGE=$(cat plan.txt)
  - >-
    curl -X POST -g -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}"
    --data-urlencode "body=${MESSAGE}"
    "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID}/discussions"
```

results:
pipeline failed

```
$ MESSAGE=$(cat plan.txt)
$ curl -X POST -g -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" --data-urlencode "body=${MESSAGE}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID}/discussions"
/bin/bash: line 179: /usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long
```

how to fix my issue

Comment: if i test in my console , i have a good result why ?

Comment: same message with the command cat

Comment: cat plan.txt in my pipeline :    /bin/cat: Argument list too long

Comment: $ cat plan.txt
/bin/bash: line 171: /bin/cat: Argument list too long